# Adding total on checkout with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have to add a total to my checkout page. I can not figure out how to create this total from my code. So far I have the sub-total per item which multiplies the number of items by the cost of the product, but not the total of the purchase.

I am not sure if I have to create a trigger on my Database or if I can create a `function` with PHP.

Also I tried to create an array from the `$total_price`, but it did not work.
I would like the total of the purchase was below the `$total_price`.

```
<?php
//check for cart items based on user session id
$get_cart_sql = "SELECT st.id, p.prod_name, p.prod_price,
st.sel_prod_qty  FROM
store_shoppertrack AS st LEFT JOIN product AS p ON
p.prod_id = st.sel_prod_id WHERE session_id =
'".$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']."'";
$get_cart_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $get_cart_sql)
or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
if (mysqli_num_rows($get_cart_res) < 1) {
//print message
$display_block .= "<p>You have no items in your cart.
Please <a href=\"seestore.php\">continue to shop</a>!</p>";
} else {
//get info and build cart display
$display_block .= <<<END_OF_TEXT
<table>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Total Price</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
END_OF_TEXT;
while ($cart_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_cart_res)) {
$id = $cart_info['id'];
$prod_name = stripslashes($cart_info['prod_name']);
$prod_price = $cart_info['prod_price'];
$prod_qty = $cart_info['sel_prod_qty'];
$total_price = sprintf("%.02f", $prod_price * $prod_qty);
$display_block .= <<<END_OF_TEXT
<tr>
<td>$prod_name<br></td>

<td>\$prod_price <br></td>
<td>$prod_qty <br></td>
<td>\$ $total_price</td>
<td><a href="removefromcart.php?id=$id">remove</a></td>
</tr>
END_OF_TEXT;
}






$display_block .= <<<END_OF_TEXT
<tr>
<th id="total" colspan="2">Total</th>
<td colspan="2"></td>


</tr>
END_OF_TEXT;

$display_block .= "</table>";
}

//free result
mysqli_free_result($get_cart_res);
//close connection to MySQL
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: If you're storing sell price for each then SUM in select may help you

Comment: See about parametrised queries

Comment: Incidentally, you can handle this in JavaScript, which would be my preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the total by adding the necessary values inside the cycle:

```
$total = 0;
while ($cart_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_cart_res)) {
$id = $cart_info['id'];
$prod_name = stripslashes($cart_info['prod_name']);
$prod_price = $cart_info['prod_price'];
$prod_qty = $cart_info['sel_prod_qty'];
$total += ($prod_name * $prod_qty);
$total_price = sprintf("%.02f", $prod_price * $prod_qty);
$display_block .= <<<END_OF_TEXT
<tr>
<td>$prod_name<br></td>

<td>\$prod_price <br></td>
<td>$prod_qty <br></td>
<td>\$ $total_price</td>
<td><a href="removefromcart.php?id=$id">remove</a></td>
</tr>
END_OF_TEXT;
}
```

And then you can write $total into your output as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to sum the total for each item inside the while loop like this:

`$total_price_sum += $prod_price * $prod_qty;`

you can place it just above:

`$total_price = sprintf("%.02f", $prod_price * $prod_qty);`

After the while loop you can format the price:

`while ($cart_info = mysqli_fetch_array($get_cart_res)) {
...
};
$total_price_sum = sprintf("%.02f", $total_price_sum);`

And then place the `$total_price_sum` variable in the $display_block.